# Rails 4 enum - how to test equality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I am using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1.1

I have a line in my user model:

```
enum role: [:user, :admin, :team_admin, :domain_admin, :super_admin]
```

In my controller I want to only do something if my user is a `:domain_admin` and I use the following test:

```
if @user.role == :domain_admin
```

The test returns false when `@user.role` (in the console) returns `:domain_admin`. So the value is set properly, but I must be misunderstanding testing equality of it, or enum's do not work as I previously thought. I assumed from reading the documentation that they were a thin layer over (small) ints.

Could anyone tell me how I test equality for `:domain_admin`, and also how do I test `>= :domain_admin`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@user.domain_admin? # return true if :domain_admin
```

instead:

```
@user.role == :domain_admin
```

use:

```
@user.role == "domain_admin"
```

Some test:

```
=> User.roles
=> {"user"=>0, "staff"=>1, "admin"=>2}
=> u = User.last
=> u.role
=> "user"
=> u.role == "user" # <-- this 
=> true
=> User.roles.each_pair { |x, _| puts u.role == x }
=> true
=> false
=> false
```

Comment: Is there any way to check if it lies in a range of these enums please? I mean, say, test if the user is a :domain_admin or higher?

Comment: For posterity, user.domain_admin? can be used, which I think you said first time - I have switched to this form for equality check